# Not able to Catch Element using SAX Parser

Tags: java, sax

I'm reading XML file using SAX parser utility.

Here is my sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><company><Account AccountNumber="100"><staff><firstname>yong</firstname><firstname>jin</firstname></staff></Account></company>
```

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ReadXML {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

                boolean bAccount = false;

                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
                        throws SAXException {

                    System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);


                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ACCOUNT")) {
                        bAccount = true;
                    }

                }

                public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

                    System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

                }

                public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

                    System.out.println("Im here:" + bAccount);

                    if (bAccount) {
                        System.out.println("Account First Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                        bAccount = false;
                        StringBuilder Account = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int i = start; i < ch.length - 1; i--) {
                            if (String.valueOf(ch[i]).equals("<")) {
                                System.out.println("Account:" +Account);
                                break;
                            } else {
                                Account.append(ch[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            };

            saxParser.parse("C:\\Lenny\\Work\\XML\\Out_SaxParsing_01.xml", handler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see in XML, `Account` tag is something like this `Account AccountNumber="100"`, What I want to do is, I want to capture Tag too as well.

So to achieve that, in `characters` method, I'm trying to read the array from right to left, So that I could get the `Account AccountNumber="100"`, when `Account` encountered as event.

But am not able to reach there, The event is getting generated, but its not going to `characters` method. I think it should go into `characters` method once Account tag is encountered. But its not..!

May I know please what am missing or doing wrong ?

Any Help please..!

Comment: Lenny - Any feedback on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65439593/10819573)?

Answer (score 0):

`AccountNumber="100"` is an attribute  of the `Account` element so inside the `startElement` handler you have you can read out the `attributes` parameter to access that value.